# searching multiple Object Value in another Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

I have 2 array of object in that, I want to compare all of the first array object property and value present in the second array of object. (at the object level.)

array 1

```
 [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3"
  }
]
```

array 2

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1",
    "other": "other"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2",
    "other": "other"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3",
    "other": "other"
  }
]
```

In this case it will return **true** because, all of array 1 values present in array 2.

but if I have one property value that does not match with array 2, that will return false.

```
 [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id5",
    "name": "name3"
  }
]
```

This will return false because { "id": "id5","name": "name3"} does not present in the array2.

I'm trying to compare with two for loop but I wanted to return false only once after both loop completes comparing all properties and value.now,

here is the two loops I'm trying, I know this is wrong because, it will return false when there is no value find and it will not go into the further loop.

```
for (var i = 0,   i < a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, j < b.length; j++) {
    if (b[j].id === a[i].id && b[j].name === a[i].name) {
      console.log('all values found');
      return true;
    }
    console.log('some values does not found');
     return false;
  }
}
```

I'm also using lodash.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question.

Comment: Don't return in the loops.  Default a variable to true and then set it to false if any elements are not found.  Then at the end, return that variable.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will prove useful for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.intersectionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy), and compare the length of the result with the length of the shorter array:

```js
var arr1 = [{"id":"id1","name":"name1","other":"other"},{"id":"id2","name":"name2","other":"other"},{"id":"id3","name":"name3","other":"other"}];
var arr2 = [{"id":"id1","name":"name1"},{"id":"id3","name":"name3"}];
var arr3 = [{"id":"id1","name":"name1"},{"id":"id5","name":"name3"}];

var result1_2 = _.intersectionBy(arr2, arr1, 'id').length === arr2.length;

var result1_3 = _.intersectionBy(arr3, arr1, 'id').length === arr3.length;

console.log(result1_2);

console.log(result1_3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object properties have the same order, this could solve your problem:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2"
  }
],
array2 = [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1",
    "other": "other"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2",
    "other": "other"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3",
    "other": "other"
  }
];

let present = true,
item,
property,
properties;

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length && present; i++) {
    item = array1[i];
    properties = Object.keys(item);

  for (let j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
    property = item[properties[j]];

    if (item.hasOwnProperty(properties[j])) {
      if (property !== array2[i][Object.keys(array1[i])[j]]) {
        present = false;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple an ugly way is to turn your objects into strings and compare them but this requires your object to have the same properties

```
 var a1 = [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3"
  }
];

var a2 = [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1",
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2",
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3",
  }
];

var a3 =  [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id5",
    "name": "name3"
  }
];


var doesArrayBContainArrayA = function(a,b)
{
  var u = [];
  a.map(e => 
        {
          var match = false;
          b.forEach(function(bx){
            if(!match){
             match = JSON.stringify(bx) === JSON.stringify(e);  
            }
          });
          if (!match){ 
              //console.log(JSON.stringify(bx)+'--'+JSON.stringify(e));
              u.push(e);   //add non existing item to temp array
            }

  });
  return u.length === 0;
}
var result = doesArrayBContainArrayA(a3,a2);
var result2 = doesArrayBContainArrayA(a1,a2);
console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```